# Hash a String into fixed bit hash value

Tags: java, hash

I want to hash a word into fixed bit hash value say 64 bit,32 bit (binary).

I used the following code

```
   long murmur_hash= MurmurHash.hash64(word);
```

Then  murmur_hash value is converted into binary by the following function

```
   public static String intToBinary (int n, int numOfBits) {
        String binary = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < numOfBits; ++i) {
           n/=2;
           if(n%2 == 0)
              {
               binary="0"+binary;
              }
           else
               binary="1"+binary;
         }

     return binary;
   }
```

Is there any direct hash method to convert into binary?

Comment: You can use `Integer.toBinaryString(int)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert into a fixed binary string, that is, always get a 64-character long string with zero padding, then you have a couple of options. If you have Apache's StringUtils, you can use:

```
StringUtils.leftPad( Long.toBinaryString(murmurHash), Long.SIZE, "0" );
```

If you don't, you can write a padding method yourself:

```
public static String paddedBinaryFromLong( long val ) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( Long.toBinaryString(val));
    char[] zeros = new char[Long.SIZE - sb.length()];
    Arrays.fill(zeros, '0');
    sb.insert(0, zeros);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This method starts by using the `Long.toBinaryString(long)` method, which conveniently does the bit conversion for you. The only thing it doesn't do is pad on the left if the value is shorter than 64 characters.

The next step is to create an array of `0` characters with the missing zeros needed to pad to the left.

Finally, we insert that array of zeros at the beginning of our `StringBuilder`, and we have a 64-character, zero-padded bit string.

---

Note: there is a difference between using `Long.toBinaryString(long)` and `Long.toString(long,radix)`. The difference is in negative numbers. In the first, you'll get the full, two's complement value of the number. In the second, you'll get the number with a minus sign:

```
    System.out.println(Long.toString(-15L,2));
```

result:

```
-1111
```

```
    System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(-15L));
```

result:

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110001
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this

```
Integer.toBinaryString(int i)
```

Comment: But the returned value is long ..is there any problem to use your code by cast long into int

Answer (score 0):

Another other way is using

```
Integer.toString(i, radix)
```

you can get string representation of the first argument i in the radix ( Binary - 2, Octal - 8, Decimal - 10, Hex - 16) specified by the second argument.